# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

The code is a simple Trie implementation in c++14. When executing the `add("name")` function following error pops-up: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20))

Follows below some debugging images:

[image]

[image]

Follows the code below:

```
struct TrieNode {
  string value;
  unordered_map<char, TrieNode *> children = {};
};

class Trie {
 public:
  TrieNode *root = new TrieNode;

  TrieNode *find(string query);

  int countPartialFind(string query);

  void add(string value);

 private:
  void add(string value, TrieNode *node);

  TrieNode *createNewNode(string &value, int counter, unordered_map<char, TrieNode *> &children);

  void add(string value, int counter, TrieNode *node);

  TrieNode *findNode(char query, unordered_map<char, TrieNode *> &children);
};

TrieNode *Trie::find(string value) {
  TrieNode *tmpNode = root;
  for (int counter = 0; counter < value.length(); counter++) {
    tmpNode = findNode(value[counter], tmpNode->children);
    if (tmpNode == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  return tmpNode;
}

int Trie::countPartialFind(string query) {
  TrieNode *matchNode = find(query);
  if (matchNode == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  return matchNode->children.size();
}

void Trie::add(string value, int counter, TrieNode *node) {
  for (; counter < value.length(); counter++) {
    node = findNode(value[counter], node->children);
    if (node == NULL) {
      node = createNewNode(value, counter, node->children);;
    }
  }
}

TrieNode *Trie::findNode(char query, unordered_map<char, TrieNode *> &children) {
  unordered_map<char, TrieNode *>::const_iterator search = children.find(query);
  if (search == children.end()) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return search->second;
}

TrieNode *Trie::createNewNode(string &value, int counter, unordered_map<char, TrieNode *> &children) {
  TrieNode *newNode = new TrieNode;
  newNode->value = value.substr(0, counter + 1);
  char tmp = value[counter];
  children[tmp] = newNode;
  return newNode;
}

void Trie::add(string value) {
  if (value.length() == 0) { return; }
  int counter = 0;

  TrieNode *tmpNode = findNode(value[counter], root->children);

  if (tmpNode == NULL) {
    tmpNode = createNewNode(value, counter, root->children);
  }

  add(value, ++counter, tmpNode);
}
```

The issue should be trivial but I can't catch it. Thanks for helping, it there is any other optimizations or code design that could be done please let me know.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with your debugger to find which line actually triggers the exception?

Comment: Yes but didn't catch it, sorry, the error could be so stupid that then I'll be ashamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 3 parameter `Trie::add` function, when you call `createNewNode`, `node` is known to be `NULL`.  The 3rd parameter, `node->children`, dereferences a NULL pointer, resulting in Undefined Behavior and, in this case, a crash.

If you look up the call stack at the values of the local variables you can see this.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was really stupid, thanks again.